# Is there a way to use bind mount, in docker, for a single file only

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume, persistent-storage

I was trying to run a simple docker container with bind mount, so the application can read and modify `data.json` file (from host machine). I placed `data.json` in `/home/usr/project` and ran the container with

```
docker container run -it -v /home/usr/project:/app container_name main.exe
```

project contains 3 files, rest of the 2 files were included in `container build`. When I try to run the container, it gives the error about the other 2 files being not found. Placing those files in `/home/usr/project` on local host solves the issue. Since, I want the container to only look for `data.json`, is there any way I can do it without keeping other 2 files unnecessarily in the bind mount directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map individual files in docker

`docker run -it -v /home/usr/project/data.json:/app/data.json alpine cat /app/data.json`

And you can even make them readonly *inside the container* to avoid unwanted modifications

`docker run -it -v /home/usr/project/data.json:/app/data.json:ro alpine cat /app/data.json`

Comment: thanks. worked perfectly. also, just a side note, if more than one files are required I believe we can put them in a sub directory and point to that directory as well